# Ruby `send` vs `call` method

Tags: ruby

I'm reading an article about Ruby 1.9. There are a lot of uses of the `call` method with `Object`.

But with a recent version of Ruby, I get this:

```
BasicObject.methods.include? :send # => true
BasicObject.methods.include? :call # => false
Object.methods.include? :call # => false

def foo
  puts 'text'
end

Object.send :foo # => text
Object.call :foo # => NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for Object:Class
```

I think that in some version of Ruby (probably 1.9), method was renamed. But I'm not sure. Please make it clear.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What method do you think was renamed to what?

Comment: With `Object`. I'we edited question. I thought it is clear from console log.

Comment: It is still not clear.

Comment: I don't remember :call has ever been defined on Object. Can you post a link to that article as well?

Comment: Yep. http://nashbridges.me/procs-and-lambdas

Comment: The objects on which `call` is called in the linked text are all lambdas and proc objects.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To begin with, `send` and `call` are two very different methods.

In ruby, the concept of object orientation takes its roots from Smalltalk.  Basically, when you call a method, you are *sending* that object a *message*.  So, it makes sense that when you want to dynamically call a method on an object, the method you call is [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-send).  This method has existed in ruby since at least 1.8.7.

In ruby, we also have a concept of "blocks".  Blocks are the `do...end` things attached to the end of method calls.  Blocks can be traditionally `yield`ed to; or, it is entirely possible to create an object out of a block (a [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html)), and pass that around.  In order to execute the block, you can call [`call`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-call) on the block.

`call` has never been defined on `Object`, whereas `send` is defined on everything.

*(note: for some reason, `call` doesn't seem to have documentation in the 2.3.0 documentation; however, it still exists and does the same thing from 2.2.0, so I linked that one instead.)*

Comment: Huge thanks for so full and clear answer! You covered all my spaces. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBelyakov no problem :~)